# Checking if IP is blacklisted

Tags: ip-address, blacklist

I have an experimental site I am working on which accesses another website for information and data and calls several times a day for a few seconds. It's been working fine for about 6 months, but the data which it's now returning is partial or incomplete.

How do I check whether my webserver is blacklisted for this other particular site?

Comment: Simple answer? No. You cannot. Short of a 403 error, there are many ways to block access to a site.

Answer (score 2):

The big question is if you have permission to query the said server? If so, you should ask them to check if it is blocked.

If you are getting partial data (not empty) the your IP is definitely not blocked. It could well be something to do with the connection to or from the server.

Comment: I have sent them an email. The data I am getting now is publicly available. I even tried querying the server via another IP address and it provided me with all the data, then within a few hours, this new IP also got blocked, and the information stopped being displayed. It appears that my own server has been blocked, but also that they have implemented some measures to restrict bots